# How to Show scores/ save Game/ load game Python?

Tags: python, list, text

I am struggling with this code, I have my menu working to make the game run and to collect scores up to 18 for each player. But I think I have gotten lost in my code and I am frustrated beyond belief.
I need to have the Player scores loaded to a list that can be saved (save game), displayed(show scores) and list current winner, and then load (load game)

```
Player_1 = []
Player_2 = []

def main():
    choice = 0
    while choice != 6 :
        print("1: New Game")
        print("2: Play Round")
        print("3: Show Scores")
        print("4: Save Game")
        print("5: Load Game")
        print("6: Exit Game")

        choice = input ("Option Select: ")

        if choice == "1":
            print("New Game // Reset Game")
            ResetGame()
        elif choice == "2":
            print("Play Play Round")
            PlayRound()
        elif choice == "3":
            print("Show Scores")
            ShowScores()
        elif choice == "4":
            print("Save Game")
            SaveGame()
        elif choice == "5":
            print("Load Game")
            LoadGame()
        elif choice == "6":
            print("Thanks for playing!")
        else:
            print("I don't understand your choice.")
def PlayRound():
    holes = 0
    index = 0
    endRound = 0
    while holes <= 18 and endRound != 1:
        Player_1Score = int(input("Player 1 Stroke: "))
        Player_2Score = int(input("Player 2 Stroke: "))
        endRound = int(input("Would you like to Continue 0= YES 1= NO"))
        if Player_1Score > 5:
            Player_1Score = 5
        if Player_2Score > 5:
            Player_2Score = 5
        Player_1.insert (index,Player_1Score)
        Player_2.insert (index,Player_2Score)
        holes += 1
        index += 1 
    print (Player_1)
    print (Player_2)
    
def ShowScores():
    total1 = sum(Player_1)
    total2 = sum(Player_2)
    if total1 < total2:
        print("The Current Winner is Player 1")
    elif total1 > total2:
        print("The Current Winner is Player 2")
    elif total1 == total2:
        print("The Players are Tied")

def SaveGame():
    with open("score1.txt","w") as P1:
        for S1 in Player_1:
            P1.writelines(str(S1)+' ')
    with open("score2.txt", "w") as P2:
        for S2 in Player_2:
            P2.writelines(str(S2)+ ' ')
    print('Your Scores have been saved.')

def LoadGame():
    with open("score1.txt", "r") as P1:
        for S1 in Player_1:
            P1.split(' ')
            print(P1)
    with open("score2.txt", "r") as P2:
        for S2 in Player_2:
            P2.split(' ')
            print(P2)
    print('Game Loaded')

def ResetGame():
    Player_1.clear()
    Player_2.clear()
    print('Scores():', Player_1, Player_2)

main()
```

Comment: Have a look at the [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) module.

Comment: I can't sadly, this is an assignment that requires loops and functions, we haven't covered pickle so i cannot use it to solve my issue. Thank you tho!

Comment: `Player_1Scorecard = open("score1.txt", 'w')` then `score1.write(Player_1)` You name it one thing then try to use it with a different name.

Comment: don't you get error message? Always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: first `writelines()` (with char `s` at the end) is for writing many lines at once - so it need list of strings but you use single string - and this should raise error. You need `write()`  to save single string.

Comment: as for reading: using only `P1` can't get text from file - you need `P1.read()` to get all text, or get all as list of lines `P1.readlines()`, or `for line in `P1:`, or `list(P1)`